# java NIO performance in multiple selectable channels VS single socket blocking I/O

Tags: java, performance, sockets, nio, low-latency

My question is regarding understanding and usage of multiple socket connections using NIO selector with a single thread. How does Selector toggles between different socket connections? Is it prompted by OS interrupts?

Also, when multiple channels have activity at the same time, how does selector choose which one to accept/read? If its not able to read at the same time ( like blocking socket ), then, does it introduce a latency/performance issue while toggling and keeping up?

Lastly, how does selector compare in performance to blocked socket reads? Assuming sufficient CPU cores are available and context switching of threads is not an issue.

Comment: Your question is a good one, but is it appropriate for stackoverflow? I'm not so sure. If a question is so broad that a good answer would take pages then it's probably not appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: Selectors in general have far better performance than any alternative.  The single thread managing a single selector is probably the most popular (i.e., best) model.  As for "how does Java manage it" a selector is an [OS level construct/system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)) so it's handled in the kernel.  At that level, DMA is usually used for data transfer, and a single interrupt is generated when the data is complete.

Comment: @JamesKPolk so I’m trying to get a performance answer for toggling between different sockets using a single selector and 1 thread. How does 1 selector avoid backlogging of data from different sockets while all those are raining data? It can read only one at a time.

Comment: @markspace thanks Mark. It think your answer is closer since we can use direct buffer to write to mmap files thus avoiding unnecessary buffers however, backlog is one that I’m trying to get an answer for.

Comment: Don't use memory mapped files in Java though.  Since Java's garbage collector can't deal with direct OS pointers, there's *no way to release memory mapped files.*  Memory mapped files is fine for something like a DLL where the memory is static, but not for large data files.  Use direct buffers and write them through NIO.  Direct buffers can be reused, mmapped files can't.